# Magento keeps admin looping

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

Hello i currently have the problem where magneto just redirects back to login page when i successfully login. Its version 2.4.5 which I installed I didn't upgrade from another version. Why would magneto do this if my credentials are correct? I see no errors

I saw some suggestions to try another browser(same thing happened) I also cleared all cookies in each browser when trying to get it to work. I also deleted cache and generated folders and it also doesn't work.Any thoughts?

Comment: i see this allot in the debug log'tries to reorder itself towards 'user', but their parents are different: 'header' and ''(its different names) '

Answer (score 0):

Use Private windows to resolve this issue and also take care following thing

- check In web/cookie/cookie_domain value is null in core_config_data table in the database.
  [core_config_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssv5h.png)

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and dirty solution you can usually open an incognito window and log in for cookie-related login loop issues.